# Restricting code-server to a specific directory?

Tags: server, chroot

Would be awesome to get a guide/doc on how to setup chroot for a user account and start code-server under that user.

so I'm wondering if there's any way to restrict code-server's access to a specific directory,

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this would be running code-server inside a container and mounting any directory you'd like accessible.

https://github.com/cdr/code-server/blob/v3.6.1/doc/install.md#docker

```
docker run -it -p 127.0.0.1:8080:8080 \
  -v "$PWD:/home/coder/project" \
  -u "$(id -u):$(id -g)" \
  codercom/code-server:latest
```

Change the -u flag to indicate user you'll be running code-server as.